# Mod rewrite not rewriting as it should

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is original URL:

```
http://myurl.com/entertainment/act-view.html?act_name=good-duo
```

Which I want to be able to write instead as:

```
http://myurl.com/entertainment/good-duo
```

Here's what I'm trying but get 500 Internal Server Error

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^entertainment/([^/]*)$ /entertainment/act-view.html?act_name=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting 500 because of looping since your regex is this:

```
^entertainment/([^/]*)$
```

Which matches URI before and after rewrite i.e. of these

```
/entertainment/good-duo
/entertainment/act-view.html
```

You can use this rule:

```
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^entertainment/([^/]*)/?$ /entertainment/act-view.html?act_name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

OR this:

```
RewriteRule ^entertainment/([^/.]*)/?$ /entertainment/act-view.html?act_name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```